# Turn back to the same position on the previous page

Tags: angularjs

Let's say: now, i'm in the index.html page.

Index.html contains all products that a company have, such as cars.

I have scrolled to a certain position on that page.

Then, i click a product (car) on that position. That brings me to a new page which display the car's detail.

When i click '**back**' button on Chrome browser. I want the browser to display the same position (product that i was clicked).

[image: Back Button]

How can i achieve this. Any idea ?

Comment: Some browsers (including Chrome) do this automatically. But if that's not working on your particular page for some reason you can use `localStorage` to note the ID of the clicked element and then on page load go back specifically to that element.

Comment: It seems not work in my web app. I also use Chrome Browser version 58.x (64 bit). Obviously, i use angularjs v1.6 to build my web app.

Comment: Is it a single page app (SPA)?

Comment: yes, it is @nnnnnn

Comment: Is it possible to take (x, y) coordinates of clicked item and set it.  Then use window.top and window.left methods to navigate to that position.

Comment: Before redirecting to the new page that show the details of the car, please capture the scroll position from event.target. When you hit back scroll to that position.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the Id(of selected car) in session storage and while you click back button, you need to go to previous page and then use session storage to go that particular location(last choosen car). try this. It will surely work.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
.run(function($rootScope, $anchorScroll) {
        $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function() {
            $anchorScroll();
        });
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

hope this will help

**Try this**

```
history.back();
```